# Custom Elements v1 in transpiling from Typescript to ECMAScript 5 failing under IE11

Tags: typescript, web-component

I'm running into trouble getting a simple web component to work when transpiled to ES5.  It appears to function perfectly fine under chrome, Edge, and Firefox, but IE11 is failing in the component's constructor with "The custom element constructor did not produce the element being upgraded."

## UPDATE

The excellent work of Oliver Krull below has clearly pinned down the problem to Typescript's compiler output.  Is it possible to make it work?

The original source (in TypeScript):

```js
import "./AppDrawer.less"

class AppDrawer extends HTMLElement {
    get open() {
        return this.hasAttribute("open");
    }

    set open(val: boolean) {
        val ? this.setAttribute("open", '') : this.removeAttribute('open');
    }

    get disabled() {
        return this.hasAttribute("disabled");
    }

    set disabled(val: boolean) {
        val ? this.setAttribute("disabled", '') : this.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }

    static get observedAttributes() { return ["open"] };

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.addEventListener("click", () => {
            this.open = !this.open;
        })
        this.textContent = this.open ? "OPEN": "CLOSED";
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
        this.textContent = this.open ? "OPEN": "CLOSED";
    }
}


customElements.define("app-drawer", AppDrawer)
```

The output (`bundle.js`):

```js
(function () {
'use strict';

function __$styleInject(css) {
    if (!css) return;

    if (typeof window == 'undefined') return;
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('media', 'screen');

    style.innerHTML = css;
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    return css;
}

__$styleInject("app-drawer {\n  color: red;\n}\n");

function __extends(d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
}

var AppDrawer = (function (_super) {
    __extends(AppDrawer, _super);
    function AppDrawer() {
        _super.call(this);
    }
    Object.defineProperty(AppDrawer.prototype, "open", {
        get: function () {
            return this.hasAttribute("open");
        },
        set: function (val) {
            val ? this.setAttribute("open", '') : this.removeAttribute('open');
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Object.defineProperty(AppDrawer.prototype, "disabled", {
        get: function () {
            return this.hasAttribute("disabled");
        },
        set: function (val) {
            val ? this.setAttribute("disabled", '') : this.removeAttribute('disabled');
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    Object.defineProperty(AppDrawer, "observedAttributes", {
        get: function () { return ["open"]; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });

    AppDrawer.prototype.connectedCallback = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.addEventListener("click", function () {
            _this.open = !_this.open;
        });
        this.textContent = this.open ? "OPEN" : "CLOSED";
    };
    AppDrawer.prototype.attributeChangedCallback = function (attr, oldVal, newVal) {
        this.textContent = this.open ? "OPEN" : "CLOSED";
    };
    return AppDrawer;
}(HTMLElement));
customElements.define("app-drawer", AppDrawer);

}());
```

And my HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.0-rc.8/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.0-rc.8/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"></script>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-drawer open disabled></app-drawer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get [custom elements v1](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) working cross browser we need to add [this](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements/blob/master/src/native-shim.js) native-shim ([here](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements#known-issues) more infos about it).

This works well in all major browsers (edge, safari, firefox etc..) but doesn't in ie11!

When we try to import it in ie11 we get a bunch of syntax errors because the shim is written with some es6.

A simple workaround is to compile the shim to  es5 and add it in addition of the es6 version (first es6, then es5 to omit errors).

This isn't the cleanest solution, but at least it works.

I created a [repo](https://github.com/Mindcraft1/custom-element-ie11) with a working example (your app-drawer (removed the `disabled` attribute because of conflicts)).

Again, it's not verry clean but it works ;-)

Comment: @mseddon did my answer help you out?

Comment: Okay, I've tried native-shim (added before bundle.js), and observe that it does now run in Edge, FF and Chrome! But IE11 is still raising the same error, and I could just compile to ES6 for the rest.  Is there a way to get it working across all platforms including IE11?

Comment: Oh, I also had to remove `custom-elements-es5-adapter.js` in order to get things working under Chrome.

Comment: @mseddon I'm at the office right now, i will look at it today evening (CEST, UTC+2)

Comment: UPDATE: custom-elements-es5-adapter.js is actually just `native-shim.js`! so by reordering those two script tags, things are fine, but IE11 is still hosed currently.

Comment: @mseddon Ok I took the native-shim which is written in es6 and compiled it to es5 + bundled it, wen i import it in ie11 there are no errors anymore and the connectedCallback is fired, the problem i'm facing now, is that the click listener doesn't work, but the text content is set. Do you want me to send you the file in some way? so you can make more trials with it? Sorry i don't have the full solution yet ;-) and not that much time.

Comment: @mseddon It works, the problem with the eventlistener is because of the disabled attribute initialy set on the app-drawer. You have to use it differenty like checking disabled == true or false (or something similar). Then your ie11 issue will be solved :-) Tell me if you want me to describe it in details into the answer.

Comment: Hi! That sounds great! Not at a computer right now but if you could put the details in your answer I will try tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Btw I am confused since I read here https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements/issues/26  the native shim is not supposed to be transpiled to es5. I was under the impression that it only repairs browser's that already implement custom element v1 natively. Either way it seems you are close to the correct solution, nice job! I think this work may help others lost in that issue, too

Comment: Regarding the event listener, it may be unrelated to this question so no need to sweat that, really I am after getting IE11 vaguely working - feel free to remove the disabled attribute, it sounds like a different SO question

Comment: Ok I will write it down and read your link (today evening again ;-))

Comment: Could you perhaps put up a git repo with your solution, too?

Comment: @mseddon Edited answer and created repo. hopefully this is enough, don't know a better way to solve this yet.

Comment: I've read your link, confuses me a little bit too. For me  it looks like they don't care about older browsers. If you want to have it clean my solution is not right.

Comment: Wee. Okay, so I tried your repo, it works! But... if you remove the es5-shim, it still works in IE11 :).  You have been an immense help though, thanks for all your work.  I now believe it is *typescript's* ES5 class transpilation causing this issue, whereas your babel example works well.

Comment: Oh really? :-) Didn't noticed that. Glad you sorted it out. But when using your bundle.js i had to add the es5-shim to get it work. dDo you think this deserves to accept the answer or does it need some edits?

Comment: I just tried using my old bundle with your shim, and... it works exactly as described.  That's really confusing.  Assuming it doesn't cause further issues it does however mean that I can remove my babel-transpilation step.  I will accept your answer for now, and try and figure out how it's working.  Thanks

Comment: Another way to solve it is to use https://github.com/WebReflection/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-classes. A similar solution should be included in Babel 7 out of the box, and Babel 7 was just released, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @trusktr is this something similar to [babel-plugin-transform-custom-element-classes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-custom-element-classes)? using this meanwhile. But don't know if it solves something for ie11

Comment: @OlivierKrull Yeah, sounds similar.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that Typescript's ES5 class implementation is incompatible with the `custom-elements-v1` shim. The immediately obvious solution, then, is to configure TypeScript to generate ES6 and pass it through Babel for transpilation.

```js
let rollupTs = rollupTypescript(require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions);

rollup({
    entry: "src/client/main.ts",
    plugins: [
        rollupTs,
        less({insert: true}),
        resolve({module: true, jsnext: true, main: true}),
        babel({
            presets: [
                [es2015, { modules: false } ]
            ],
            plugins: ["external-helpers"],
            exclude: "node_modules/**"})
    ],
    dest: "bundle.js",
    format: "iife"
})
```

However, see the accepted answer- it seems that by adding the es5 transpiled shim to the typescript generated code fixes TypeScript's ES5, while having no effect on babel compiled code.  I've accepted it since it's a fairly trivial drop-in fix for this issue, with the caveat that *I don't actually understand why it works*