# What is the ES5 way of writing web component classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component

To define a custom web component, we can extend an ES6 class to get access to the element's *lifecycle reactions*.

```
class HelloElement extends HTMLElement {
  // Monitor the 'name' attribute for changes.
  static get observedAttributes() {return ['name']; }

  // Respond to attribute changes.
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (attr == 'name') {
      this.textContent = `Hello, ${newValue}`;
    }
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('hello-element', HelloElement);
```

What is the ES5 way of doing the equivalent?

Comment: Consider using composition instead of inheritance. Even with the new capabilities in ES6, sometimes composition is still a better solution.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question body. Do you want to know how to extend `class`es (defined with ES6 syntax) with ES5 syntax, or do you want to know how the prototype inheritance was done with ES5?

Comment: @spanky, Agreed.  The reason for the questions is because I'm intending to use a functional compile-to-JS language for a project and am considering using web components.  I don't yet know how if the language (ReasonML) can compile to ES6 classes, and was wondering if there was an ES5 way to do the equivalent. I am under the impression that ES6 classes are not a new feature, but rather a syntactical sugar over ES5 prototypical inheritance.

Comment: @Bergi, You're right.  I've updated.  I'm wondering how I could use web components in an ES5 syntax.  I've just realized that I could probably use Babel to find out what it would transpile to.

Comment: _"I don't yet know how if the language (ReasonML) can compile to ES6 classes"_ Why do you not know? Have you tried?

Comment: `I could probably use Babel` - this

Comment: @guest271314 Not yet.  According to the Bucklescript manual, the output is ES5 so it seems that it can't currently compile to ES6 classes.

https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/Manual.html

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Does your Answer resolve Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Please do not extend DOM objects via their prototype, see [*What's wrong with extending the DOM*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). At the very least, you should check that *HTMLElement* exists and is extendable.

Comment: Note:, the babel output did not work.  Error:

` TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

Will be reading @RobG recommended post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ES5 way of writing web component classes. [Web components require ES6 features](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/423), there is no way around that. If you cannot use ES6 `class` syntax because your transpiler doesn't emit, you need to at least use ES6 `Reflect.construct` for creating custom elements with your own prototypes.

Alternatively, the [custom elements polyfill appears to work with ES5 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43427281/1048572), at least in most browsers.

Comment: I wish this wasn't the case!

Answer (score 12):

Based on your comments I assume you mean ES6 *syntax*, and are allowing ES6-defined functions that Custom Elements-supporting browsers also support.

To simulate the default ES6 constructor that calls `super()`, we can use [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct) to invoke the `HTMLElement` constructor but using the prototype from our `HelloElement` consutrctor.

For inheritance, you need to set the `.prototype` of the `HelloElement` constructor to an instance of `HTMLElement` and define methods and properties on that. It's conventional to use use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create a non-functional dummy instance without invoking the constructor here.

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define your static getter for `observedAttributes`, but it will usually just be a static list and you can simply set `HelloElement.observedAttributes` to an array of attribute names instead.

```js
function HelloElement() {
   return Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], HelloElement);
}
HelloElement.prototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

// Monitor the 'name' attribute for changes.
Object.defineProperty(HelloElement, 'observedAttributes', {
  get: function() { return ['name']; }
});
// or just use HelloElement.observedAttributes = ['name']
// if it doesn't need to be dynamic

// Respond to attribute changes.
HelloElement.prototype.attributeChangedCallback = function(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
  if (attr == 'name') {
    this.textContent = `Hello, ${newValue}`;
  }
}

customElements.define('hello-element', HelloElement);

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('example').setAttribute('name', "World");
}, 1000);
```

```html
<hello-element id="example"></hello-element>
```

Comment: This is a great solution. While I would love to use it, I can't in an older browser since `Reflect.construct` is an ES6 operation and does not work in older browsers.

But I still like it!!

Comment: I was looking for this! :D I'll give it a try later and see if it works for my use case. I want to define a custom element from rust without going to JS land, I can't create a class from rust but I can use the usual web APIs :)

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't really work very effectively for ECMAScript 5 and lower with DOM nodes. You can add to the host prototypes if you wish, but you're not going to get an actual, clean subclass.

This is why object wrappers were sometimes used for DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) method to do this, but this is an ES6 feature.

```
function CustomElement() {
    return Reflect.construct(HTMLElement, [], CustomElement);
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomElement.prototype, HTMLElement.prototype);
Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomElement, HTMLElement);

customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

```
var elem = document.createElement('custom-element');
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

This will append `<custom-element></custom-element>` to the `body`.